# Convert char to Time format without NA coercion

Tags: r, char, datetime-format, posixct, strptime

### Example of Data in question:

```
start_end$started_at
    [1] "2/7/22 15:47"  "3/21/22 20:05" "3/22/22 7:24"  "3/5/22 12:49"    
        "1/10/22 8:24"  "1/23/22 7:47"
```

```
start_end$start_time <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(start_end$started_at)), 
           format="%H:%M",tz="UTC")
```

I keep getting NA output when attempting to convert char to numeric or time format.

I know that column `started_at` needs to be converted from character to numeric which is why I used `as.numeric` and `as.character` but I keep getting NA coercion. I've tried `as.POSIXct` and `strptime`.

> Warning message:
> In as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(start_end$started_at)), format = "%H:%M",  :
> NAs introduced by coercion

Also Tried:

```
StartTime2 <- strptime(start_end$started_at, "%H:%M:%S")
```

I've tried these so far

```
start_end$start_time <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(start_end$started_at)), 
           format="%H:%M",tz="UTC")



StartTime2 <- strptime(start_end$started_at, "%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Base R does not have a “time” data type only datetime.  You will need to parse both the date and time portion of the string.  See example in the help for strptime

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those times when you can make it a challenge or *really easy*. The library `lubridate` is phenomenal for dates. Notice the function, `mdy_hm`; I bet you can tell what it means: month, day, year, hour, minutes.

```
library(lubridate)

sta <- c("2/7/22 15:47", "3/21/22 20:05", "3/22/22 7:24", "3/5/22 12:49",
         "1/10/22 8:24",  "1/23/22 7:47")
sta2 <- mdy_hm(sta)
# [1] "2022-02-07 15:47:00 UTC" "2022-03-21 20:05:00 UTC" "2022-03-22 07:24:00 UTC"
# [4] "2022-03-05 12:49:00 UTC" "2022-01-10 08:24:00 UTC" "2022-01-23 07:47:00 UTC"
```

As you can see, it defaulted to Greenwich time. You can set your time zone, as well.

```
sta3 <- mdy_hm(sta, tz = "EST")
# [1] "2022-02-07 15:47:00 EST" "2022-03-21 20:05:00 EST" "2022-03-22 07:24:00 EST"
# [4] "2022-03-05 12:49:00 EST" "2022-01-10 08:24:00 EST" "2022-01-23 07:47:00 EST"
```